# Matlab saving file as name defined within other variable

Tags: matlab, variables, save

I want to load multiple variables into one .mat file at the end of a process loop. I have a simple line of code :

```
save draw.mat Output
```

but I cannot work out a way to code 'use the name given by variable X' instead of 'Output', so that I can loop the process and save multiple variables in draw.mat

So then

```
X = 'Chocolate'
```

and the Variable name is saved as Chocolate.

I am sure it is simple but I cannot find a solution on here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `-struct` form of the `save` command. You build a struct with fields holding the names of the variables in the resulting .mat-file.

Example:

```
s = struct();
s.VariableOne = 1;
s.VariableTwo = 2;
save draw.mat -struct s;
```

The file draw.mat will now hold two 1x1 double variables with names "VariableOne" and "VariableTwo".

You can also build the struct in one single command:

```
s = struct('VariableOne', {1}, 'VariableTwo', {2});
```

Or you can use the `cell2struct` function:

```
data = {1,2};
names = {'VariableOne', 'VariableTwo'};
s = cell2struct(data(:), names(:), 1);
```

Answer (score 4):

You need the functional form of SAVE. In other words, SAVE can be called like this:

```
save('draw.mat', 'Output1', 'Output2');
```

So, if your variable names to save are in a separate variable, you could do

```
v1 = 'Output1';
v2 = 'Output2';
save('draw.mat', v1, v2);
```

Or even

```
v = {'Output1', 'Output2'};
save('draw.mat', v{:});
```

The [SAVE reference page](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/save.html) has full details.

Comment: And also:  S = 'draw.mat'; save(S, v1, v2)

Answer (score 0):

Let

```
A = [2 5 8; 25 2 4; 4 1 7];
save('A.mat')
```

Now you want to save it with other name say `B`

```
B = A;
save('B.mat')
```